# Как конвертировать int в DateTime c#

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, datetime

В VK Api возвращается date в странном виде, в виде числа и непонятно как его расшифровывать.

Скрин:

[image: 1]

И как это перевести на человеческий? Мне нужно перевести это в DateTime в c#, но как я понял переводить можно только со string. Как с int я не нашел инфы

Comment: Это Unix TimeStamp (по этим словам можно искать решение), конвертировать [легко](https://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/12888024).

Comment: Это количество секунд прошедших с 1го января 1970  года.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это дата в формате UnixTime

```
public DateTime DateTimeFromUnixTime(long unixTimeStamp)
{
    return DateTimeOffset
         .FromUnixTimeSeconds(unixTimeStamp)
         .UtcDateTime;
}
```

Пример использования (при вводе инта, но лучше сразу JSON конвертировать в лонг, а не инт)

```
var mydate = DateTimeFromUnixTime( 1597509237L );
```

Comment: Не компилируется, мне кажется вы перемудрили с экстеншном, я сначала удивился, а потом не нашел способа сделать статический экстеншн метод, ну видимо потому что это не возможно сделать. Далее, автор вопроса спрашивал, как `int` преобразовать, а не `string`. А пока название класса напрашивается `StringExtensions`, а пример `"1597509237".FromUnixTime()`, хотя и название метода становится странным в этом случае.

Comment: Так же не плохо было бы объяснить автору, что если использовать `int`, то 19.01.2038 в 03:14:07 (`int.MaxValue`) его приложение перестанет работать. Поэтому рекомендуется использовать `long`.

Comment: да, согласен. Ща исправлю. А по поводу инта - там на самом деле стринг же - это ведь работа с JSON

Comment: Json string идёт с кавычках а numeric нет

Comment: готово, оформил как метод вместо екстеншна